# delete(key) function in hive flutter not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

dlete frome hive local database in flutter is not working. `delete(key)` is not working
but `deleteAt(index)` is working fine

this is my code where database operations located

and i want to delete a data with the id of the data. i dont get any error its not working and if i click delete button its correctly printing id but not deleting with that id im a beginner in dart and flutter

```
import 'package:money_manager/functions/lists.dart';
import 'package:money_manager/models/transactions.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> addData(Transactions data) async {
  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

   Hive.init(dir.path);

  final db = await Hive.openBox<Transactions>('transaction_db');

  await db.add(data);

  print(data);

  transactions.value.add(data);

  transactions.notifyListeners();
}

Future<void> getAllTransactions() async {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

   Hive.init(dir.path);

  final db = await Hive.openBox<Transactions>('transaction_db');

  //await db.clear();

  transactions.value.clear();

  transactions.value.addAll(db.values);

  transactions.notifyListeners();
}

Future<void> deleteData(int index) async {

  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  Hive.init(dir.path);

  final db = await Hive.openBox<Transactions>('transaction_db');

  await db.delete(index);

  print(index);

  getAllTransactions();


}
```

My database model is

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
part 'transactions.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Transactions {
  @HiveField(0)
  final int id;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String title;

  @HiveField(2)
  final int amount;

  @HiveField(4)
  final DateTime dateTime;

  @HiveField(5)
  bool isIncome;

  Transactions(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.amount,
      required this.dateTime,
      required this.isIncome });
}
```

i want to delete with `@HiveField(0) final int id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await db.add(data);
```

This will *auto-generate* a key for you. If you want to use *your* key, you actually have to do so:

```
await db.put(data.id, data);
```